# Using PNG images in OpenGL textures

Tags: c, opengl, png, textures

I'm using OpenGL 1.4 and I would like to use a PNG image in an OpenGL texture. This is the code I used to initialize the texture (using SDL 1.2 and SDL image):

```
GLuint texture;
SDL_Surface *surface;
surface = IMG_Load("image.png");
glGenTextures(1,&texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,surface->w, surface->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
```

image.png is a 128x128 sized PNG image located in the same folder as the executable. Here is a screenshot of what I get:

[image: problem]

To compare, here is the original image:

[image: originalimage]

I tried exactly the same code with a bitmap image and it worked just fine.

Why does it do this? What is the correct way of doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the problem.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,surface->w,surface->h,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,surface->pixels);
```

Your `format` parameter is incorrect. It should be:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,surface->w,surface->h,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,surface->pixels);
```

`GL_RGBA` (not `GL_RGB` will represent 8 bits per channel which is what I think you need in your solution.)

Please refer to https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml for more information.

Comment: `GL_RGBA8` is not a valid `format` enum. It is only allowed as `internalFormat`. For the client side, `format` basically describes only the number and order of the channels, and `type` the data format for each element, so `GL_RGBA`, `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is probably the right choice.

Comment: @derhass I tried `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,surface->w,surface->h,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,surface->pixels);` (with `GL_RGBA`) and it worked just fine.

Comment: With `GL_RGBA8`, the whole thing turns white. It should be `GL_RGBA` as derhass said.

Comment: Agreed @derhass is right. Approved his correction. Thanks.